# Alternative to deprecated get_io_service()

Tags: boost-asio

Asio v 1.11. The doc says that `basic_stream_socket::get_io_service()` member function is deprecated and `get_executor()` must be used instead. But the latter returns `executor` not `io_service`.

How to obtain reference to the `io_service` object used by socket to construct another one?

Comment: (boost::asio::io_context&)(basic_stream_socket).get_executor().context(); works for me.

Comment: Unchecked type casts is a bad idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_executor().context()`:

```
socket newSocket(existingSocket.get_executor().context()));
```

Comment: ssl::stream has a lowest_layer() socket

Answer (score 3):

Since ASIO v 1.13 new I/O object can be constructed using just the executor:

```
socket new_socket{existing_socket.get_executor()};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation points to comment, I write as an answer:

Using `get_executor().context()` did not work right away for me, but writing a macro did (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67281460/boostasio-get-io-service-alternative-in-boost-1-70/67773642#67773642))

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid using answert to post comments.

Comment: @tropappar I've upvoted some of your answers to hopefully give you enough rep to comment :P