# Boost::asio get_io_service() alternative in boost 1.70+

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to use a library (https://github.com/onlinecity/cpp-smpp) and it's based on boost 1.41. But in our project, we are using 1.72.

There is a code there that gets io_service from a TCP socket (`socket->get_io_service()`[here](https://github.com/onlinecity/cpp-smpp/blob/0f9195d14956cd306a962d36344ba8526cf5eab9/src/smpp/smppclient.h#L494)). Then this object is used in the following parts of the code:

```
deadline_timer timer(ioService);
```

and

```
ioService.run_one();
ioService.reset();
```

But `get_io_service()` is removed from boost 1.70+. What functions and objects I should use instead of those in such situations?

UPDATE

There is another question ([Alternative to deprecated get_io_service()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445636/alternative-to-deprecated-get-io-service)) that is similar to mine, but the answers in that question do not work in the scenario of this one.

Comment: How did those answers not work in your case? What have you tried and what was the error?

Comment: I  tried answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445636/alternative-to-deprecated-get-io-service. The output of `get_executor().context()` is null.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this commit: https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/commit/3da41d770ca0e021f597bef30ffe6fcefe3e6959

It defines a macro

```
#if BOOST_VERSION >= 107000
#define GET_IO_SERVICE(s) ((boost::asio::io_context&)(s).get_executor().context())
#else
#define GET_IO_SERVICE(s) ((s).get_io_service())
#endif
```

and replaces the calls

```
socket.get_io_service()
```

with

```
GET_IO_SERVICE(socket)
```